# Bluetooth Low Energy costum Service device discovery and development for Windows 8.1 Store Apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, driver, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-8.1, gatt

I started building Windows Store App, but after I discovered that my device is not discovarable on Windows 8.1 compared to Windows 7 and IPhone on which I can detect this Blutooth LE device.
I am using following PrimaryServices:

- Generic Access (0x1800)
- General Attribute (0x1801)
- Costum service (0x13B0)
- Device Information (0x180A)

How can I make this device discovarable and usable later in Windows Store Apps (writing some kind of driver, change some services on device or as a last option write specification for costum service this is too expensive for me at the moment)?
Mutiple solutions for this problem are welcome.

Comment: Did you try to pair the bluetooth LE device with your computer/phone/tablet first? I was bitten by that one just now, coming from Android development...

Comment: No. I can not pair something that PC does not see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through Windows 8's UI to pair with Bluetooth Devices. You cannot control the pairing programmatically.

If what you describe is that you cannot discover your Bluetooth device, even on Windows 8's UI, then there must be a compatibility problem:

- Your dongle on Windows 8 may be classical (below 4.0) while the device is strictly Low Energy (4.0)
- Your dongle's driver was not properly installed